# Classification of compact Shimura curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, shimura-varieties

Is there a classification that determines all isomorphism classes of compact Shimura curves at least Shimura curves in $A_g$? I did not find this in the literature and appreciate any helpful information. By compact Shimura curve I mean Shimura curves associated to quaternion algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$